# How to create different data frames to store data while running for loop function? (I don't want to overwrite)

Tags: r, for-loop, dataframe

I am running for loop function with a list, and I ran into a problem because R overwrites the data as it goes through the loop and only shows the result of the last loop. I tried rbind but it did not work for my purpose, as I want to save each component of list in separate data frames (they are time series data). Any help would be appreciated.

Edit: 
Here's shortened version of my code. To my knowledge, as they are looping through the series, each data frame from different currency should be saved in their corresponding currency name, but the data frame is saved as "curr" not the currency name itself and only contain the dataset from USDGBP.

```
for (curr in list("USDEUR Curncy","USDJPY Curncy","USDGBP Curncy"){
  c <- bdh(c(curr), c("PX_LAST", "MOV_AVG_200D"), 
          start.date=Sys.Date()-365*yr, 
          options = c("periodicitySelection" = "DAILY"))
  curr <-data.frame(c)
}
```

Comment: It'll be easier to help if you provide some sample data and the code that you're facing problems with.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. I attached the sample data.

Comment: Add `curr <- vector("list",3)` before the loop, loop over an index variable `i` instead of `curr` and then change `curr <- ...` to `curr[[i]]` <- ...`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `assign`, which assigns a `name` to an object.

For example,

```
# creates an object "x" of value 2
assign("x", 2) 
> x
[1] 2
```

In the case of your loop, you can try:

```
for (curr in list("USDEUR Curncy","USDJPY Curncy","USDGBP Curncy")){
  c <- bdh(c(curr), c("PX_LAST", "MOV_AVG_200D"), 
           start.date=Sys.Date()-365*yr, 
           options = c("periodicitySelection" = "DAILY"))
  assign(paste0(curr), as.data.frame(c))
  }
```

This will create each `data.frame` as a different object in your global environment

Comment: Thanks a ton! This is exactly what I wanted (and it works). I searched through this forum a lot to resolve this issue, but I never saw this function before. Thanks again.